# Reassign migrated question

Tags: support, user-accounts, migrated-questions

A question of mine was moved from SO to SU, but *before* I had an superuser account. Now the question is assigned to a non-existing user (grey text), and I can't edit the question or accept answers.

Can the question be reassigned to my new SU account? They are both merged, so it can be proven, that the two people are me.

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136280/killing-the-windows-shell-closed) or [SU](https://superuser.com/questions/5131/killing-the-windows-shell), that is the question...

**Update:** I followed the answer below and asked the support. For other people with this problem, if you read this question: This came back:

> This isn't quite possible yet but it is coming soon. Keep an eye on the blog!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you associate your multiple accounts together, you should regain control. If that did not work, you should email team@stackoverflow.com to get the situation sorted out.

Comment: Hm. Obviously it did not work. I'll drop an e-mail then, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There really should be more of an indicator, when a question gets moved, about how to regain ownership.

It could be just a link in the moved question, or a link in the person's recent activity page.